# comment_post_ID 0 (cannot remove from dashboard)

Tags: comments, database, security

Ran across something a bit odd that I haven't seen before. A client has a pretty active blog and uses Akismet (paid) to protect against spam. At least once a day, they're reporting a spam comment that is correctly marked as spam, but cannot be removed from the admin dashboard by clicking `Empty Spam` or manually selecting the entry and trying to delete it.

I looked into this and noticed that the DB entry has a `comment_post_ID` of `0`, which I'd have to assume means it is not attached to any post. I can obviously remove them manual from the DB (and it works just fine), but haven't found any information on what this could be.

I've replaced the core WP files (thinking it might be a security issue) and also re-generated the salts/keys in the `wp-config.php` file without any change.

Any thoughts would be a huge help. thanks!

## Update

While this may have stemmed from, I'm not sure if it is the result of the [InMotion hack](http://dreamdare.org/blog/how-to-fix-inmotion-hosting-hack-tiger-mate/).

Here's what's been done:

- Changed FTP, MySQL passwords
- Created new DB user, assigned to database
- Updated salts/keys in `wp-config.php`
- Changed all WP user passwords
- Re-installed core WordPress files

Akismet is out of ideas on this one (don't blame them) as this one is persistent.

Comment: If a comment is posted without a post ID the ID is set to '0'. Look in `/wp-comments-post.php`. The next few lines should kill the script though, unless you have a post with ID '0'. And that is puzzling, which is why this is a comment and not an attempt at an answer.

Comment: Yeah - this one's a head-scratcher for sure

Comment: Is there any other pertinent information recorded in the wp_posts record? A consistent author, email, or agent? Might be helpful clues.

Comment: Sorry mean the wp_comments record, not wp_posts. Didn't catch it in time to edit the comment.

Comment: Nope - authors, IPs agents, etc. all different from the four I'm seeing. Unless I want cheap timberlands or home-made bags, I'm still stumped ;)

Comment: Are there any other plugins which can causes the problem? Maybe a plugin hook into 'comment_id_not_found' and insert the comment. This hook will be called before wp-comments-post.php exit.

Comment: Another idea. Grab the spammers IP from the DB and search for it in the server logs. Which url has the spammer requested?

Comment: do a grep on comment_save_pre and see if there's a function that alters the data before it is saved. It's not possible to add a comment without an (open to comments) post number, so it has the be changed after reception.

Some questions: Are there custom post types, do you use ajax to submit comments (plugins). Are you using captcha plugins.

Comment: Hi all - appreciate the continued interest in this one. A few responses: No plugins that hook into either `comment_id_not_found` or `comment_save_pre` (did have a plugin called Easy Comment Uploads previously, but is unpublished and can't find original files - now using [Comment Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-images/)). The access logs have yet to reveal any matches for these IP addresses (which also don't match), but [searches](http://www.stopforumspam.com/ipcheck/49.212.187.105) confirm they are spam (if that wasn't obvious already ha).

Comment: I wonder if there was some sort of a race condition. For instance, a post was published, a comment was incoming, and at just the right instant, the post was deleted.

Comment: Can you provide a list of all plugins installed and active on that site at the times when you get one of these comments?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry can't comment here but i'll try to help.

wp_handle_comment_submission function handing comments posting contains exact check for post_id:

```
    $post = get_post( $comment_post_ID );

    if ( empty( $post->comment_status ) ) {
         ...
       return error_happened; 
    }
```

i.e. 
(1) it passes through , or 
(2) comment was added other than default way of posting comments.

For (1) - check that post with id=0 doesnt exists in db, wp_posts table. Sometimes failures in database cause presence of such records