# Wordpress admin bar showing pending comments which cannot be selected or modified after deleting parent page

Tags: comments

My Wordpress admin interface shows there are 4 pending comments, but I've already approved three and deleted one of them via Disqus comment moderation page, but the page they were posted on was later deleted. I then posted two comments myself on a test page, deleted the page, and they are still shown as pending on Wordpress admin. How do I remove them from pending comments list?

Page the comments have been posted to is removed, so they do not have anything in "in response to" column, these comments also do not have a checkbox next to them, so I can't select them. There are also no options appearing when hovering above the comment on pending comments moderation page.

I just recently installed WordPress to my site and it doesn't have anything custom but Disqus.

---

I am absolutely new to WordPress, so please explain each step of possible solution in detail.

Comment: In a brief test, if I delete a page, its associated comments are deleted as well. Maybe [troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) and [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Also, check if [this Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/71859/12615) is related.

Comment: This happens every time I remove a page with comments, and I only have Disqus installed from custom plugins, so I'm wondering if this is a unique situation. Surely someone else must have had this problem before.

Comment: Do you active use of caching, like APC or Memcached and also active in Backend, liek via Dropin inside the `wp-content` folder or as plugin?

Comment: I don't understand anything of that. I'm just a simple user who encountered a problem and described it in a way that may suggest I'm an experienced user, but I'm not.

Comment: But very often have also simple users a caching plugin or a server, there use caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the next plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/delete-all-pending-comments/

**Note:** I haven't tested this plugin reproducing your issue exactly, but the plugin I created to delete all pending comments.

Please let me know :)

Comment: Well that worked. Now I just need to find out how to prevent this kind of behavior.

Comment: Glad that have worked for you! :) By "behaviour", what do you mean? Like in the future, when deleting a page, to delete also attached pending comments?

Comment: I'd like them to stay attached to the deleted page at least, so they can be selected and deleted manually. Not sure how this must work, but I think it's logical that you don't ever want to be unable to do something with your content.

Comment: Yes but a pending comment attached to a deleted page, it means it is deleted too like it's parent page.

Comment: Except in my case it's not. I think it loses some id which is required to do things, and this results in absent checkboxes and action buttons.

Comment: You mean the pending comments were siblings? What is the concrete "behavior" you are trying to avoid for the future? Please explain step by step. I can try to help you :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7279/discussion-between-gravuj-miklos-henrich-and-user1306322)

Comment: I already explained it several times. When a page is deleted, attached comments become unmanageable.

Comment: And when a page is deleted, the normal way is to be deleted also all attached comments to this page automatically. :) So if a page is deleted, there should not exist any unmanageable comments.

Comment: Yes, and as I've stated, in my case it isn't so for some reason.

Comment: "I'd like them to stay attached to the deleted page at least" this confused me. Sorry. I may suggest for you the WordPress Support forum. Your problem occurs when deleting a page, normally comments are gone.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reset it by editing a row in the wp_options table, option_name = _transient_wc_count_comments

In my case, all of the comments were WooCommerce reviews, so your option_name may be different (search the option_value column for your total comment count).

Be careful editing serialized data (look it up if it isn't clear!).